# Android Room: Insert several entities with relations

Tags: android, database, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I have a trouble with insertion to ROOM db, when we have several inner relations like one-to-many
A -> B and B -> C. I haven't problem to insert and get all list A, but not for list B and list C. 
I not find correctly tutorial for these cases.
Pojo and entities:

```
data class AB(
    @Embedded
    var a: A,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "id",
        entity = B::class,
        entityColumn = "aCreatorId"
    )
    var bList: List<B>
)

@Entity
data class A(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int = 0
) {
    @Ignore
    var bList: List<B>? = listOf()
}

@Entity
data class B(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int = 0,
    var aCreatorId: Int
) {
    @Ignore
    var cList: List<C>? = listOf()
}

@Entity
data class C(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int = 0,
    var bCreatorId: Int
)
```

How insert list of B and list of C correctly and get it after in object A ?